# How to build a database that contain only the delta from yesterday

Tags: sql-server-2008

I need to know what has been changed on my database since last night.
Is it possible to extract this data from the LDF file and to build a new Database that contains the delta?

For example, let say I have a table for users and now, a new user was added and one of the users update his home address. I need to be able to build a new database that users table will contain two records
1. The new user (and to add a new column to know if it’s new or update field)
2.  The user that update his record (it will be nice to know which record has been update)?

BTW,
I have to SQL servers that I can use (2008 and 2012)

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: While this is possible could you explain why you need to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to look at "Change Data Capture" feature: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645937.aspx

This feature is only available with SQL Server Enterprise Edition.
Or try this Codeplex project for SQL Server Standard Edition: https://standardeditioncdc.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

What about triggers on insert, update and delete? You can insert this data in history tables or whatever you want to call it and have queries or views that check only depedening on your time requirement. Here is an example (kt2008 is db name, chassis is my entity name):

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS kt2008.chassis__ai;
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS kt2008.chassis__au;
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS kt2008.chassis__bd;

CREATE TRIGGER kt2008.chassis__ai AFTER INSERT ON kt2008.chassis FOR EACH ROW
INSERT INTO kt2008.chassis_history SELECT 'insert', NULL, NOW(), d.* 
FROM kt2008.chassis AS d WHERE d.id = NEW.id;

CREATE TRIGGER kt2008.chassis__au AFTER UPDATE ON kt2008.chassis FOR EACH ROW
INSERT INTO kt2008.chassis_history SELECT 'update', NULL, NOW(), d.*
FROM kt2008.chassis AS d WHERE d.id = NEW.id;

CREATE TRIGGER kt2008.chassis__bd BEFORE DELETE ON kt2008.chassis FOR EACH ROW
INSERT INTO kt2008.chassis_history SELECT 'delete', NULL, NOW(), d.* 
FROM kt2008.chassis AS d WHERE d.id = OLD.id;
```